# Get RSS response using angular $http

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I'm trying to get an RSS response using $http and I keep getting the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

The code that tries to get it is:

```
$http({
            method: 'jsonp',
            url: url,
            params: {
                format: 'jsonp',
                callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
            }
        }).success(function (response) {
            myData = response;
        });
```

Comment: Try post form for method.

Comment: getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin error when changing to post

Comment: You need to load your file directly from webserver, not with file:/// protocol, by the way, you can download them with $http.get in case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use googleapi to get the feed:

```
function getFeed(url, count) {
    var deffered = $q.defer();
    $http
        .jsonp('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=50&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url))
        .then(function(response) {
            if (!response.data.responseData) {
                return CommonSrv.handleError('Unable to fetch RSS feed from provided URL. Please check the URL.');
            }
            var feeds = response.data.responseData.feed.entries;
            var result = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                var f = feeds[i];
                f.publishedDate = new Date(f.publishedDate).toISOString();
                result.push(f);
            }
            deffered.resolve(result);
        }, CommonSrv.handleError);
    return deffered.promise;
}
```